# Web2py How to return data from controller after an ajax call

Tags: ajax, web2py

I have a sign in page,the page send request to the controller and show errors after getting back the result.
This is the ajax call in sign in page

```
$.ajax({
url:"signin", //changed into temp.html page
data:{
    username:$username,
    password:$password,
    email:$email },
success:function(errCode){
    if(errCode==0){
        alert('Error,wrong username/password');
    }else{...}
    },
    type:'POST'
});
```

The problem is in controller def signin() I don't know how to return the data's value back to ajax,it either didn't work or wiped the page clean and printed just the data's value.How can I do it,is it the same if I want to return a javascript  type file?

Edit:I found a way to work around it,I changed the ajax request destination to a temp page and return the value directly.Here is my view function in controller

```
def signin():
return dict()
def temp():
errCode=0
return errCode
```

Comment: Please include the full error traceback you have received. Also please show us your signin view as well...

Comment: Thank you but somehow the problem solved itself.All I did was just add

    def signin():
    return(errorCode=0)

And it did show the alert box after submitting,honestly I don't understand why,I did try this before but it only worked just now.
Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Better include your code, Without your code how we know your problems...

Comment: Sorry about this,by "including my code" did you mean all of them?The html,js and the code in controller?

Comment: Relevant code only. In this case I would like to take look of singin view function and jquery ( You already posted this )